# Alternative word to describe 'pigeon-holing' someone to win an argument

Tags: single-word-requests

I see this a lot on the internet, twitter etc. As an example say some random democrat is in a debate with a republican. Whatever the topic was, the democrat might say something along the lines of 'anyway you're probably just a racist so I don't care what you say...'. It's where the opposing party 'picks' one or more of the worst possible cases about 'you', factual or not, and just uses them to paint you as being 'worthless' or at least not worth debating with, ergo they win the argument. Another example might be someone trying to describe their belief in a 9/11 conspiracy. The opposing side might say 'yeah and you believe the moon landings were fake and JFK etc etc'. The conspiracy theorist may or may not hold those beliefs, but the opponent in this case just paints the picture that they do so they can be safely dismissed.

Does that make sense? is there a word for when people do that?

Comment: sounds similar to  an _ad hominem_ attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a combination of logical fallacies. Mostly an **ad hominem** attack (attacking the person, not their argument), but also a touch of **red herring** (distracting with facts/claims irrelevant to the original topic).

> **Argumentum ad hominem (argument directed at the person).** This is the
> error of attacking the character or motives of a person who has stated
> an idea, rather than the idea itself. The most obvious example of this
> fallacy is when one debater maligns the character of another debater
> (e.g, "The members of the opposition are a couple of fascists!"), but
> this is actually not that common. A more typical manifestation of
> argumentum ad hominem is attacking a source of information -- for
> example, responding to a quotation from Richard Nixon on the subject
> of free trade with China by saying, "We all know Nixon was a liar and
> a cheat, so why should we believe anything he says?" Argumentum ad
> hominem also occurs when someone's arguments are discounted merely
> because they stand to benefit from the policy they advocate -- such as
> Bill Gates arguing against antitrust, rich people arguing for lower
> taxes, white people arguing against affirmative action, minorities
> arguing for affirmative action, etc. In all of these cases, the
> relevant question is not who makes the argument, but whether the
> argument is valid.
>
> **Red herring.** This means exactly what you think it means: introducing irrelevant facts or arguments to distract from the
> question at hand. For example, "The opposition claims that welfare
> dependency leads to higher crime rates -- but how are poor people
> supposed to keep a roof over their heads without our help?" It is
> perfectly valid to ask this question as part of the broader debate,
> but to pose it as a response to the argument about welfare leading to
> crime is fallacious.
>
> [[Logical Fallacies and the Art of Debate - CSUN](http://www.csun.edu/%7Edgw61315/fallacies.html#Red%20herring)]

Answer (score 3):

Terms like "ad hominem" and "straw man" (attacking the person rather than his argument, or switching to an argument you *can* easily win) don't *exactly* describe what's going on in OP's example context.

If someone says *Since you voted for Trump, you're a misogynistic racist whose opinions are worthless,* what they're doing is ***stereotyping***...

> [**stereotype**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stereotype) (noun)
> *a set idea that people have about what someone or something is like, **especially an idea that is wrong***

(Where ***typecast*** and ***pigeonhole*** are effectively synonyms for the derived verb sense.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you mean, but a [**straw man**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) argument is defined at Wikipedia as:

> [...] a form of argument and an informal fallacy of having the impression of refuting an argument, whereas the proper idea of the argument under discussion was not addressed or properly refuted. One who engages in this fallacy is said to be "attacking a straw man".

This means that instead of actually engaging in the subject of the argument, you're attacking a much easier-to-destroy exaggerated version of the subject.  For example:

> A: "I think that many of our drug laws are too harsh."
>
> B: "Oh, so you think that children should be able to buy heroin at the grocery store?"

Here, B is "attacking a straw man" by implying that A has advocated for a complete repeal of any and all laws restricting drug use, when in fact they never said that.